# iOS Local Notification - Callback when in Background

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

Context:
My iOS App uses local notifications
I schedule local notifications and then I get a call back via *didRecieveLocalNotifications* when the notifications fire.

This works fine when the app is in **foreground** however when the App goes in the **background** I get the iOS notification **but no call back**.

My Question:
How can I get a callback from iOS when the app is in background.

Here is the call back code -

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:    (UILocalNotification *)notification
{

    //call your method that you want to do something in your app
    NSLog (@"Received Notification");
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    [myRootController HandleLocalNotifications:notification];

}
```

Comment: What "callback" do you get in the foreground? Show your code, please, so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: Updated to show call back code

Comment: Very good, thanks. See my answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are describing `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`. This is deprecated in iOS 10. You should be updating to the UserNotification framework.

Now then.

If you app is *frontmost*, the user gets no alert. Instead, *you* get `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`.

If your app is *not frontmost*, the user gets an alert. Therefore, you do *not* get `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` because the notification fired. But you *do* get it if the *user* received the notification *and summoned your app* by tapping the notification alert. If the user does that, you will get `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` even in the background.

If your app was terminated in the background, however, you will get `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (and you can check the `options` to learn that you're being launched because of the notification).

If your app was in the background or not running, and the user does *not* tap the notification and summon your app, you will get nothing at all and will have no way to know that the notification fired. This is because notifications are not for *your* benefit but are a way of sending a message to the *user*. (It sounds, from your question, as if you may be misusing local notifications as a way of sending a message to *yourself*. That is not what they are for.)

Comment: Aha - Thanks I understand it now.
Followup - lets say your app needs to do something at noon everyday as long as its either in foreground or background.  What is the best way of accomplishing that?

Comment: That is not what you asked. If my answer was right and helped you, I hope you'll accept it. If you have a different question, I hope you'll ask a new question — except don't ask that one, because it has been asked and answered many times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks - answer accepted.  Can you point me to the answer to my followup.  Most answers suggest using UILocalNotification for that and hence my original question

Comment: I don't think that's a good answer. After reading it I feel like getting notification callback when app is in background is something illegal. Though there are definitely some cases when it would be nice to have this call back. E.g I have my watch paired to iPhone. Notification comes to iPhone when app is in background/killed. I want to check whatever is said in notification on my watch. But apparently there is no way that my watch would know that notification has fired on iPhone, cuz app there was in background. That's not right.

Comment: Hi @Shalugin what's the problem exactly?

Comment: Hi @matt I guess the problem is not so wide spread, but it can be the case that we need to get notification call back when app is in background. Like in my example when I have app on the watch in foreground, notification fires on iPhone where app is in background. I would like to check notification out on the watch (let's say I got some reminder), but I can't fetch any data from iPhone because there is no notification call back.

Comment: @Shalugin A local notification is not something sent to your app. It is sent to the user on your app's behalf. If your app is in the background when a local notification is sent to the user, you get no event, because this was never aimed at you, the app — unless the user _does_ something with that notification, in which case you can hear about that fact. If you wanted your app to be notified even in the background merely because a notification fired, you need a push (remote) notification, not a local notification.

Comment: @Shalugin However, that is no reason to call my answer "not a good answer". I am describing the fact, correctly. You may not like those facts, but my answer is accurate.

Comment: @matt you're quoting someone else dude. I didn't say that it's "not a good answer". I said that "I don't think that's a good answer". It's not  the same thing. And I explained why I think so. If you want me to repeat I got feeling that "getting notification callback when app is in background is something illegal" and I got it  from your words: "This is because notifications are not for your benefit but are a way of sending a message to the user. " It sounds quite nonsense for me, as we are here NOT to find out the ways to abuse users, but to find out the ways to make an app work. Cheers