# Handling notification in the background before user taps on them - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

In swift 3, how can I handle a local notification while the app is in the background and before the user taps on the notification?

`UserNotificationController.userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)` is only called when the user taps on the notification.

My goal is to create a local notification that displays a screen similar to an incoming call in which the user can swipe to pick up or hang up.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried in 'willPresent notification' UserNotificationdelegate method?!

Comment: That's the one I meant actually when I said it only gets called when the user taps on it. I've updated the question.

Comment: In this method you have to return the notification present option in completion handler. Until that the notification won't be showing to user. You just do your works before returning notification present options.

Comment: Do you mean that I should be calling `completionHandler()` inside the overridden method `UserNotificationController.userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`? This wouldn't solve my problem because this method doesn't get called before the user taps on the notification banner.

Comment: In what OS your are trying?!

Comment: I'm running my code on an iPhone 5S with iOS 10.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this SO question, it's simply not possible:

[iOS Local Notification - Callback when in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064835/ios-local-notification-callback-when-in-background)

Quoting part of the answer given in that link:

> If your app was in the background or not running, and the user does
>   not tap the notification and summon your app, you will get nothing at
>   all and will have no way to know that the notification fired. This is
>   because notifications are not for your benefit but are a way of
>   sending a message to the user. (It sounds, from your question, as if
>   you may be misusing local notifications as a way of sending a message
>   to yourself. That is not what they are for.)